# Does ActiveStorage use the checksum for anything?

Tags: rails-activestorage

In a very real sense, my question is actually 'can I skip generating a checksum', but answering that question rests on the above question.

To give you some background, I'm (finally) converting from Paperclip to ActiveStorage, and one of the pains of my particular conversion process is that I'm storing a decent sized number of fairly large files -- in addition to normal sized thumbnail images, I'm also storing large multimedia files, some in excess of 10GBs (currently poking at a 15GB file).

The basic conversion process has me downloading the file to generate a checksum, and a few other minor details that could be done with a head request instead of downloading the full file.  We also copy the file from it's old 'home' to its new 'home', but that is done as an S3 to S3 copy, and doesn't take as long as downloading and uploading.

I'd love to skip the download & generate checksum process -- or at least, put it off for another day, as a cleanup step that isn't important to what we're actually doing.

So the question is: does the checksum actually do anything in ActiveStorage, or is it just a 'nice-to-have' feature that would allow me to, for example, publish the checksum if someone wanted to verify their version?

Comment: I'm curious what you ended up doing / found out... I'm transcoding videos in the cloud, and want to avoid downloading them as well, and the checksum is the only thing I'm missing :)

Comment: @SunilD. nothing useful.  I wound up burning a ton and a half of bandwidth downloading the files to generate the checksum, 'just in case'.  Comcast even got upset with me when I burned TBs of data in the course of days doing a local test run without thinking it through.

Comment: Haha thanks for the reply! I've decided to also download the files so we have the checksum. The main use seems to be to verify the integrity of the initial upload to the storage service, but I believe it is also useful when mirroring content to another storage service. I also read about some people using it to check for duplicate content that may have already been uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

[Found in code Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2c5eda36c00b473281c354250848b1f8962daf64/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L249)

> Prior to uploading, we compute the checksum, which is sent to the
> service for transit integrity validation. If the checksum does not
> match what the service receives, an exception will be raised.

You can create your own checksum without downloading the file:

[Found in code Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2c5eda36c00b473281c354250848b1f8962daf64/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L371)

```
def compute_checksum_in_chunks(io)
  OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new.tap do |checksum|
    while chunk = io.read(5.megabytes)
      checksum << chunk
    end

    io.rewind
  end.base64digest
end
```